# React-Redux's mapStateToProps working in unexpected way

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component which shows a list of names fetched from the Redux store. The component looks like this:

```
class Details extends React.Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render () {
    const listName = [...this.props.listName];
    return (
      <div className="container detailsBox">
        <p>Details Grid:</p>
        {listName ? (
          listName.map((el, index) => {
            return (
              <li key={index}>
                {el}
              </li>
            )
          })
        ): null}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    listName: state.listName
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Details);
```

Notice here I only map the `listName` from the store. But the code does not display the `<li>` with the elements of `listName` even when logging in console shows `listName` is populated with data

But data shows as expected when the `name` is also fetched from the store, with this modification in `mapStateToProps`:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    listName: state.listName,
    name: state.name
  }
}
```

I am befuddled as well as curious to know why the code behaves in this unexpected way? What am I missing here?

The reducer code looks like this:

```
import { UPDATE_NAME, ADD_NAME } from '../actions/addName.action';

const initialState = {
  name: '',
  listName: new Set()
}

function rootReducer (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_NAME:
      return {
        name: '',
        listName: state.listName.add(action.payload)
      }
    case UPDATE_NAME:
      return {
        ...state,
        name: action.payload
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default rootReducer;
```

and the actions like this:

```
export const ADD_NAME = 'ADD_NAME';
export const UPDATE_NAME = 'UPDATE_NAME';

export function addName (data) {
  return {
    type: ADD_NAME,
    payload: data
  }
}

export function updateName (name) {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_NAME,
    payload: name
  }
}
```

Comment: react-redux does memoization for you through shallow comparison of previous and next props. Since your reducer mutates the listName set in place `Set.add`, it doesn't look like there any change. You should probably replace it with a different set in the reducer `new Set([...state.listName, action.payload])`

Comment: how your listName looks like?
I recommend you to use React Developer tools to check how your component is saving the listName and ReduxDevTools to check the store and whats happening there

Comment: It's typically not recommended to use Set or Map in the redux state, since they are mutable data types and optimized for mutation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happens because you mutate the state. When you mutate `listNames` it still points to the same object in memory, and react thinks that nothing is changed, while the contents of `listNames` is changed. You should return a new object.

```
case ADD_NAME:
  return {
    name: '',
    listName: new Set([...state.listName, action.payload]),
  }
```

But it is not recommended to use `Set`s in reducers. Instead you can store your `listNames` as an Array and use lodash `union` function to have only unique values.

```
import { union } from 'lodash';

const initialState = {
  name: '',
  listName: []
}

// some code

case ADD_NAME:
  return {
    name: '',
    listName: union(state.listNames, action.payload)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can instead use an object to hold the listName and then recreate the structure of your state into a new object and then return.

```
const initialState = {
  name: '',
  listName: {}
}

case ADD_NAME:
  return {
    name: '',
    listName: {...state.listName, action.payload}
  }
```